# Yolov5 in Tensorflow custom weight load

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, yolov5

Is there a way to load yolov5 in python like this:

```
model = xyz.load("yolov5", weight_path)
```

So that in model variable I have the whole architecture of yolov5

Answer (score 0):

With torch.hub.load:

```
model = torch.hub.load(
            path-to-hubconf-file(eg. yolo_dir),
            'custom',
            path=(path-to-weight-file(eg. yolov5/weights/<model_name>.pt),
            source='local',
            force_reload=True,
        )
```

An then we can use:

```
model.conf = 0.45
```